# Synchronizing Current Directory Between Two Zsh Sessions

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

I have two iTerm windows running zsh: one I use to documents in vim; the other I use to execute shell commands. I would like to synchronize the current working directories of the two sessions. I thought I could do this by outputting to a file `~/.cwd` the new directory every time I change directories

```
alias cd="cd; pwd > ~/.cwd"
```

and creating a shell script `~/.dirsync` that monitors the contents of `~/.cwd` every second and changes directory if the other shell has updated it.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(pwd) > ~/.cwd
alias cd="cd; echo $(pwd) > ~/.cwd"
while true
do
  if [[ $(pwd) != $(cat ~/.cwd) ]]
  then
    cd $(cat ~/.cwd)
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

I would then append the following line of code to the end of my `~/.zshrc`.

```
~/.dirsync &
```

However, it did not work. I then found out that shell scripts always execute in its own subshell. Does anyone know of a way to make this work?

Comment: You could try using a zsh precmd hook to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat emptor:** I'm doing this on Ubuntu 10.04 with gnome-terminal, but it should work on any *NIX  platform running `zsh`.

I've also changed things slightly. Instead of mixing "pwd" and "cwd", I've stuck with "pwd" everywhere.

### Recording the Present Working Directory

If you want to run a function every time you `cd`, the preferred way is to use the [`chpwd` function or the more extensible `chpwd_functions` array](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/42/ZSH-Gem-8-Hook-function-chpwd/). I prefer `chpwd_functions` since you can dynamically append and remove functions from it.

```
# Records $PWD to file 
function +record_pwd {
    echo "$(pwd)" > ~/.pwd
}

# Removes the PWD record file
function +clean_up_pwd_record {
    rm -f ~/.pwd
}

# Adds +record_pwd to the list of functions executed when "cd" is called
# and records the present directory
function start_recording_pwd {
    if [[ -z $chpwd_functions[(r)+record_pwd] ]]; then
        chpwd_functions=(${chpwd_functions[@]} "+record_pwd")
    fi
    +record_pwd
}

# Removes +record_pwd from the list of functions executed when "cd" is called
# and cleans up the record file
function stop_recording_pwd {
    if [[ -n $chpwd_functions[(r)+record_pwd] ]]; then
        chpwd_functions=("${(@)chpwd_functions:#+record_pwd}")
        +clean_up_pwd_record
    fi
}
```

Adding a `+` to the `+record_pwd` and `+clean_up_pwd_record` function names is a hack-ish way to hide it from normal use (similarly, the VCS_info hooks do this by prefixing everything with `+vi`).

With the above, you would simply call `start_recording_pwd` to start recording the present working directory every time you change directories. Likewise, you can call `stop_recording_pwd` to disable that behavior. `stop_recording_pwd` also removes the `~/.pwd` file (just to keep things clean).

By doing things this way, synchronization be easily be made opt-in (since you may not want this for every single zsh session you run).

### First Attempt: Using the `preexec` Hook

Similar to the suggestion of @Celada, the `preexec` hook gets run before executing a command. This seemed like an easy way to get the functionality you want:

```
autoload -Uz  add-zsh-hook

function my_preexec_hook {
    if [[-r ~/.pwd ]] && [[ $(pwd) != $(cat ~/.pwd) ]]; then
        cd "$(cat ~/.pwd)"
    fi
}
add-zsh-hook preexec my_preexec_hook
```

This works... sort of. Since the `preexec` hook runs before each command, it will automatically change directories before running your next command. However, up until then, the prompt stays in the last working directory, so it tab completes for the last directory, etc. (By the way, a blank line doesn't count as a command.) So, it sort of works, but it's not intuitive.

### Second Attempt: Using signals and traps

In order to get a terminal to automatically `cd` and re-print the prompt, things got a lot more complicated.

After some searching, I found out that `$$` (the shell's process ID) does not change in subshells. Thus, a subshell (or background job) can easily send signals to its parent. Combine this with the fact that zsh allows you to [trap signals](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions), and you have a means of polling `~/.pwd` periodically:

```
# Used to make sure USR1 signals are not taken as synchronization signals
# unless the terminal has been told to do so
local _FOLLOWING_PWD

# Traps all USR1 signals
TRAPUSR1() {
    # If following the .pwd file and we need to change
    if (($+_FOLLOWING_PWD)) && [[ -r ~/.pwd ]] && [[ "$(pwd)" != "$(cat ~/.pwd)" ]]; then
        # Change directories and redisplay the prompt
        # (Still don't fully understand this magic combination of commands)
        [[ -o zle ]] && zle -R && cd "$(cat ~/.pwd)" && precmd && zle reset-prompt 2>/dev/null
    fi
}

# Sends the shell a USR1 signal every second
function +check_recorded_pwd_loop {
    while true; do
        kill -s USR1 "$$" 2>/dev/null
        sleep 1
    done
}

# PID of the disowned +check_recorded_pwd_loop job
local _POLLING_LOOP_PID

function start_following_recorded_pwd {
    _FOLLOWING_PWD=1
    [[ -n "$_POLLING_LOOP_PID" ]] && return

    # Launch signalling loop as a disowned process
    +check_recorded_pwd_loop &!
    # Record the signalling loop's PID
    _POLLING_LOOP_PID="$!"
}

function stop_following_recorded_pwd {
    unset _FOLLOWING_PWD
    [[ -z "$_POLLING_LOOP_PID" ]] && return

    # Kill the background loop
    kill "$_POLLING_LOOP_PID" 2>/dev/null
    unset _POLLING_LOOP_PID
}
```

If you call `start_following_recorded_pwd`, this launches `+check_recorded_pwd_loop` as a disowned background process. This way, you won't get an annoying "suspended jobs" warning when you go to close your shell. The PID of the loop is recorded (via `$!`) so it can be stopped later.

The loop just sends the parent shell a `USR1` signal every second. This signal gets trapped by `TRAPUSR1()`, which will `cd` and reprint the prompt if necessary. I don't understand having to call both `zle -R` and `zle reset-prompt`, but that was the magic combination that worked for me.

There is also the `_FOLLOWING_PWD` flag. Since every terminal will have the `TRAPUSR1` function defined, this prevents them from handling that signal (and changing directories) unless you actually specified that behavior.

As with recording the present working directory, you can call `stop_following_posted_pwd` to stop the whole auto-`cd` thing.

Putting both halves together:

```
function begin_synchronize {
    start_recording_pwd
    start_following_recorded_pwd
}

function end_synchronize {
    stop_recording_pwd
    stop_following_recorded_pwd
}
```

Finally, you will probably want to do this:

```
trap 'end_synchronize' EXIT
```

This will automatically clean up everything just before your terminal exits, thus preventing  you from accidentally leaving orphaned signalling loops around.

Comment: Thank! I need to try this out!